# VBA copy from workbook to a master workbook - Error 9 UPDATE

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from one workbook to another. But I am getting Error 9 - Subscript out of range.

```
Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String

 FolderPath = "F:\Test\"

 Filepath = FolderPath & "*.xlsm"


 Filename = Dir(Filepath)

 Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

 Do While Filename <> ""
 Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & Filename)
 lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row
 lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ActiveWorkbook.Close

 erow = Sheet1111.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row


 lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 Cells(erow, 4))

 ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Baza").Range(Cells(erow, 1),         

 Filename = Dir

 Loop
 End Sub
```

---

With this code working, (error was wrong sheet name (it had name Sheet1111(Baza)), now it only copies data from last file in directory, and I want to copy data from all files.

Comment: Change `“Sheet1111”` to `"Sheet1111"`.  Also change `errow` to `erow`.  (Please insert `Option Explicit` as the first line in your code module - that will at least stop typos such as `errow`.)

Comment: Originally it was like you posted, but without Option Explicit :) Still, no success.

Comment: Actually, `Option Explicit` would have detected **both** of the errors.

Comment: So the statement `ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1111").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, lastcolumn))` crashed with an error 9 when `erow` was 2 and `lastcolumn` was 58?  (I could understand it crashing with an error saying that the sizes of the source and destination were different, but an error 9 sounds strange.)   Do you have a worksheet called "Sheet111" in your main workbook?

Comment: Only thing that I can see is Under Microsoft Excel objects - Sheet1 , Sheet11, Sheet111, and when I click on it, there isn't any code, blank editor appears

Comment: Also, is `Worksheets("Sheet1111")` the `ActiveSheet`?  I'm not sure whether it is going to be happy pasting to the `ActiveSheet` with a destination range pointing to some other sheet.  (I would suggest you just use `Worksheets("Sheet1111").Cells(errow, 1).Paste`.)

Comment: Sorry, my earlier reference to "Sheet111" was meant to be "Sheet1111".  I can see in your code that you have an object called `Sheet1111` but that doesn't mean that the sheet name is "Sheet1111", and sometimes people think that there is a one-to-one relationship between the two things.

Comment: @A.S.H - I don't think closing a workbook clears the clipboard.  I just tried (manually) doing a copy in one workbook, closing it, then pasting in another workbook and it worked, so I would think that doing the same thing programmatically should be fine.

Comment: Yes, Sheet1111 is active sheet. Still nothing.

Comment: Does `Worksheets("Sheet1111").Cells(erow, 1).Paste` (instead of `ActiveSheet.Paste .....`) give an error 9?  If so, place a `MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet1111").Name & "|" & erow` immediately before it and let us know whether that crashes and, if not, what it says.

Comment: On left side, in my Microsoft Excel Objects list stands Sheet1111(Baza)
And when I put 
MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet1111").Name & "|" & erow
error 9 occures in that row, and when I put MsgBox Worksheets("Baza").Name & "|" & erow then it prints Baza|2

Comment: (a) I would recommend you adopt a standard approach to worksheet references - you currently use four different approaches to refer to one worksheet: `Sheet1111.`, `ActiveSheet.`, `Worksheets("Baza").` and the implicit reference by not specifying anything.  The statement `ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Baza").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))` incorporates three of those methods within the one statement.  (b) Do you have anything in column A of the data being copied?

Comment: (c) `lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row` should be `lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` (perhaps that is causing the paste to fail because the data being copied will no longer fit on the destination sheet?)

Comment: It is same when I put lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, and I don't have anything in column A for copy, it contains header.

Comment: If you don't have anything in column A, don't use column A when determining how many rows have been used on your sheets.  Pick a column that has something in every filled-in row.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Reduce screen "flickering"
    Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Baza")

    FolderPath = "F:\Test\"
    Filepath = FolderPath & "*.xlsm"        
    Filename = Dir(Filepath)        
    Do While Filename <> ""
        'Provide status message showing where we are up to
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & Filename
        DoEvents

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)
        With ActiveSheet ' this isn't strictly necessary, but ensures that we can
                         ' qualify all sheet references to a consistent sheet without
                         ' any surprises
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lastcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy _
                      ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Filename = Dir
    Loop        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```